# How would I match up the following sentences with their respective negations?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

This is supposed to be done with logical identities and the rules for negation with quantifiers.

A-D are the sentences and 1-4 are the negations.

**A) ∀x(P(x) ∧ [(∃yP(y)) ∧ (∃yR(x, y)) ⇒ (∃yP(y))])**

**B) ∀x∀y(¬R(x, y) ∨ ¬P(x))**

**C) ∀x(P(x) ⇔ ∃yR(x, y))**

**D) ∀x∀y(P(x) ∧ R(x, y) ⇒ R(y, x))**

***1) ∃x∃y(P(x) ∧ R(x, y) ∧ ¬R(y, x))***

***2) ∃x([P(x) ∨ ∃yR(x, y)] ∧ [¬P(x) ∨ ∀y¬R(x, y)])***

***3) ∃x∃y(P(x) ∧ R(x, y))***

***4) ∃x¬P(x)***

Intuitively, it seems that A and C are supposed to match with one of 2 or 4 and B and D are supposed to match with one of 1 and 3. I might be wrong though.

I have tried to use these basic formulas:

***¬∀xP(x) = ∃x¬P(x)*** and ***¬∃xP(x) = ∀x¬P(x)***

but the expressions above seem the be much longer and seem to involve far more manipulation.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to those quantifier negation rules, you can also use the good old propositional logic equivalences, such as Commutation, Association, DeMorgan's Laws, laws for rewriting biconditionals and conditionals, etc.

For example, let's take B) and negate it:

$$\neg \forall x \forall y (\neg R(x,y) \lor \neg P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Quantifier Negation)}$$

$$\exists x \exists y \neg (\neg R(x,y ) \lor \neg P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (DeMorgan)}$$

$$\exists x \exists y (R(x,y) \land P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Commutation)}$$

$$\exists x \exists y (P(x) \land R(x,y))$$

OK, so that matches 3 ... can you do the others?

...

OK, you matched D correctly with 1. I would show a few more steps though:

$$\neg \forall x \forall y ((P(x) \land R(x,y)) \rightarrow R(y,x)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Quantifier Negation)}$$

$$\exists x \exists y \neg ((P(x) \land R(x,y)) \rightarrow R(y,x)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Implication)}$$

$$\exists x \exists y \neg (\neg (P(x) \land R(x,y)) \lor R(y,x)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (DeMorgan)}$$

$$\exists x \exists y ((P(x) \land R(x,y)) \land \neg  R(y,x))$$

For C, it's a good idea to rewrite the biconditional, since none of 1 through 4 contain a biconditional:

$$\neg \forall x (P(x) \leftrightarrow \exists y R(x,y)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Quantifier Negation)}$$

$$\exists x \neg (P(x) \leftrightarrow \exists y R(x,y)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Equivalence)}$$

$$\exists x \neg ((P(x) \land \exists y R(x,y)) \lor (\neg P(x) \land \neg \exists y R(x,y)))$$

... can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! So then, would I be correct in saying 
that D matches with 1, A matches with 2 and C matches with 4?

Comment: @sktsasus Before I answer that ... can you show your work? Please know that logicians never care about the answer, and only about the reasoning! :) ... also, I have to go to sleep now ... why don't you try going through the steps like I did for the other three problems and I will take a look first thing in the morning.

Comment: Ok I will! Good night!

Comment: I have posted my attempts in an answer. Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry for the late response Sir/Madam but I am still not entirely sure abut this one. So for C, would the two not's cancel out leaving just the not P(x), which is number 4. I am not entirely sure about which identities to use as none seem to work. Sorry for bothering you about this again. Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: @sktsasus No, they don't cancel out ... HINT  Do a couple of DeMorgan's

Comment: I see. So I did the DeMorgan on the second half of the bracket above and ended up getting the first half of the bracket in 2. And I then did the DeMorgan on the first half of the bracket above and seemed to have ended up getting the second half of the bracket in 2. So, does C match with 2? Thank you again!

Comment: @sktsasus Yes, you got it, very good!

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to come up with proofs for D and C, but I only managed to do the quantifier negation of A.

Could you be so kind to verify that my proofs for D and C are correct and possibly how I could proceed with the proof of A. Each of the proofs begin with their respective letter. Thank you so much!

[image]